# Is stdout a natively usable token in C++?

Tags: c++, file, stream, stdout

Say I have a function like

```
void printToSomewhere(FILE* stream, char* msg){
    fprintf(stream, "%s", msg);
}
```

If I want the stream to be `stdout`, do I have to declare that before in the calling function:

```
...
FILE* stdout;
printToSomewhere(stdout, "printing to stdout");
...
```

or can I call the function without having to define/include/etc stdout explicitly?

```
...
printToSomewhere(stdout, "printing to stdout");
...
```

Comment: Please choose one of C and C++.

Comment: Downvoted for lack of research effort.

Comment: @BaummitAugen I'm not sure what kind of 'research effort' should be used in a situation where one's not even quite sure how to word the question they're asking.

Comment: @galois I'm referring to research effort as in looking up `stdout` in some C++ reference. Both references that turn up when searching for `stdout` in an arbitrary search engine answer this question. That's like not even a minute of work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As with every variable, you have to declare `stdout` before using it. The variable `stdout` is declared in the header file `stdio.h` (or `cstdio` in C++). By including `stdio.h` (or `cstdio`), `stdout` becomes visible.

On many platforms, you can also simply declare `stdout` as an extern variable:

```
extern FILE *stdout;
```

although doing so is discouraged, as the C standard requires `stdout` to be a macro and allows it to expand to something that is not even a variable. On most plaforms however, `stdio.h` defines this macro simply as

```
#define stdout stdout
```

but you should refrain from making this assumption in portable software.

Comment: Standard says `stdout` is a macro, so `extern FILE *stdout;` does not work on some platforms.

Comment: @kakkoko Corrected wording to incorporate this fact. I totally forgot about that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. STDOUT is always file descriptor 1 (mandated by POSIX).

This will work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void printToSomewhere(FILE* stream, const char* msg){
    fprintf(stream, "%s", msg);
}

int main()
{
    FILE* f = fdopen(1, "w+");
    printToSomewhere(f, "Hello\n");
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

expected output:

```
Hello
```

Comment: Doing this might yield strange results on older Unices that use a fixed table of `FILE` pointers as the `fdopen()` call overwrites the existing `FILE` structure for file descriptor 0. Also, stdout is always file descriptor 1, not 0 and you should use the macro `STDOUT_FILENO` instead of hardcoding it.

Comment: Answer corrected, mea culpa. It's going to have to be a very old (non-posix) unix for this to be true. Surely that's a corner-case, and something unlikely to be encountered by the OP?

Comment: I'm actually not sure if it is allowed to open a file again. Let me ask.